# C# How to grep the last word from a directory path?

Tags: c#, directory, grep, cpu-word

I have a program that "greps" out various directory paths from a log text file and prints various results according to the word.

Examples of Directory paths:

- C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Desktop/AccessData FTK Imager.lnk
- C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Start Menu/Programs/AccessData
- C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/AccessData FTK Imager.exe:Zone.Identifier

Therefore how can I grep out the file or folder name after the last "/"? This is to help the program to identify between files and folder. Please do take note of the multiple "." and white spaces found within a directory paths. etc "Imager.exe:Zone.Identifier". Therefore it is difficult to use `if(!name.contains()".")`

Etc. How to get the "AccessData FTK Imager.lnk" or "AccessData" or "AccessData FTK Imager.exe:Zone.Identifier" from the path STRING?!

May someone please advise on the methods or codes to solve this problem? Thanks!

The codes:

```
if (!token[7].Contains("."))
                {    

                    Console.WriteLine("The path is a folder?");

                    Console.WriteLine(token[7]);

                    Console.WriteLine(actions);

                    MacActions(actions);

                    x = 1;
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Path class when working with file paths, and use the File and Directory class when working with actual files and folders.

```
string str1=@"C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Desktop/AccessData FTK Imager.lnk";
string str2=@"C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Start Menu/Programs/AccessData";
string str3=@"C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/AccessData FTK Imager.exe:Zone.Identifier";

Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(str1));
Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(str2));
Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(str3));
```

outputs:

```
AccessData FTK Imager.lnk
AccessData
Zone.Identifier <-- it chokes here because of the :
```

This class operates on strings, as I do not have those particular files and/or folders on my system. Also it's impossible to determine whether `AccessData` is meant to be a folder or a file without an extension.

I could use some common sense and declare everything with an extension to be a file (`Path.GetFileExtension` can be used here) and everything else to be a folder.
Or I could just check it the string in question is indeed a file or a folder on my machine using (`File.Exists` and `Directory.Exists` respectively).

```
if (File.Exists(str2))
    Console.WriteLine("It's a file");
else if (Directory.Exists(str2))
    Console.WriteLine("It's a folder");
else
    Console.WriteLine("It's not a real file or folder");
```

Comment: Please look at the question again.... There is no need to get the path name as it is already supplied to the program...

Comment: Yes but how can we differentiate if the path is a file or folder?

Comment: @JavaNoob, you can't. See my answer

Comment: @JavaNoob, it the files are local, you can check if they exist. It they are remote files, there is no sure way of knowing.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Path.GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx).

> The characters after the last directory character in path. If the last character of path is a directory or volume separator character, this method returns String.Empty.

Comment: @JavaNoob - The `Path` class is an abstraction of file paths. It lets you load any path string to extract information from it.

Comment: Yes but how can we differentiate if the path is a file or folder?

Comment: @JavaNoob - There is no way to tell. Can you tell me if this string ends in a file or a directory? `c:\mydir\docs\stuff`

Comment: The strings provided by the text file just outputs exactly what you see in the above with various endings in files and directories.

Comment: @JavaNoob - Exactly my point. Without a _physical_ file or directory, you can't look up the data. They are completely indistinguishable from each other.

Answer (score 1):

> This is to help the program to identify between files and folder

There is no way to determine is a path represents a file or folder, unless you access the actual file system. A directory name like 'Foo.exe' would be perfectly valid, and a file with no extension ('Foobar') would be valid too.

Answer (score 1):

how about tokenized it with "/" like what you're doing ... and then you'll know that the last token is the file, and whatever before it is the path.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply split the whole string by /

e.g.:

string a="C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Desktop/AccessData FTK Imager.lnk";
string[] words=a.split('/');
int len=words.length;
so now words[len] returns the data after last slash(/)..
I hope you understand...

Comment: Thats tokenizing as mentioned by aggi.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you only have a string that represents the name of the file, if that is the case you can't really be sure. It's totally ok to have a folder namen something like `Folder.doc`. So if you don't have access to the actual file system it is hard to check. You can get close though using regular expression like:

```
(.*\\)(.+)(\..*)
```

Try it on: http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html
If you get any output in group number 3 it's likely that it is a file and not a folder. If you don't get some output try this direct after:

```
(.*\\)(.+)(\..*)?
```

That will give you the folder in group 2.

Comment: Any clues on how to create that regular expressions?